# How to show Dropdown Menu when Right-Clicking on Table Row?

Tags: reactjs, antd

How do I open a [dropdown](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/) menu when a row is right-clicked in a [table](https://ant.design/components/table/)?

I've tried using Table's onRow `onContextMenu: event => { setVisible(true); }` function with dropdown outside the table `<Dropdown overlay={menu} visible={visible}><Table>...</Table></Dropdown>`, but the dropdown menu opens at the bottom of the table, not where the mouse is.

I've found a [working demo sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rm23kroqyo) but its with ant design 3.0.0 and doesn't work with the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add **visible** state in your component:

```js
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
```

Then pass the visible state into **Dropdown** component that use **contextMenu** as trigger and your **Menu** component as the overlay:

```
<Dropdown overlay={menu} visible={visible} trigger={["contextMenu"]}>
   <Table ... />
</Dropdown>
```

Add states that will keep position and value of our clicked cell:

```js
const [posX, setPosX] = useState(0);
const [posY, setPosY] = useState(0);
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
```

Next, use **onRow** attribute where we pass a Function that return **onContextMenu** and **onClick** Function at your **Table** component.
We will receive an event at *onContextMenu* by which we get the **clicked position** and use *onClick* to hide the menu

```
<Table
  onRow={(_record, _rowIndex) => {
    return {
      onContextMenu: (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // grab and keep the clicked position
        const { clientX, clientY, target } = event;
        setPosX(clientX);
        setPosY(clientY);
        // grab the clicked cell value
        setValue(target.innerHTML);
        // show the overlay Menu
        setVisible(true);
      },
      // hide the overlay Menu on click
      onClick: () => setVisible(false)
    };
  }}
  ...
/>
```

And finally, the overlay Menu positioning. Here we use inline style to set the position. Since Dropdown component default positioning is `bottomLeft` so the position will be at:

```js
left: 0  // left side
top: n // where n is the bottom of the table which is equal to the height of your table
```

This is why your dropdown menu opens at the bottom of the table.
To fix this, we need to set the top value as:

```js
// the formula
topPosition = clientY - tableHeight - menuHeight;

// in our example we get:
topPosition = clientY - 220 - 72
            = clientY - 292;
```

So the clicked position becomes:

```js
left: clientX,
top: clientY - 292
```

and at the menu we set by using inline style as follow:

```js
const menu = (
    <Menu
      style={{ top: posY - 292, left: posX }}
      onClick={onClick}
      items={[
        {
          key: "1",
          label: "Action 1"
        },
        {
          key: "2",
          label: "Action 2"
        }
      ]}
    />
  );
```

This is a minimal example:

[image: Edit polished-resonance-8kfw05]

#### Additional Info

If you need to access the row value from the menu, you can get the information from **record** props at **onRow** event handler and grab the value at **onContextMenu** event handler. So, when you do a right click at each row,  the **record** value will be set as **rowRecord** state that could be used inside **Menu** component that is rendered inside a **useMemo** hook later. Since the **menu** now have been memoized, now the **onClick** method have to use **useCallback** hook too.

```js
  const [rowRecord, setRowRecord] = useState();
  ...

  const onClick = useCallback(
    (_item) => {
      console.log(value);
      setVisible(false);
    },
    [value]
  );

  ...

  const menu = useMemo(() => {
    console.log(rowRecord);
    return (
      <Menu
        style={{ top: posY - 292, left: posX }}
        onClick={onClick}
        items={[
          {
            key: "1",
            label: rowRecord?.name
          },
          {
            key: "2",
            label: rowRecord?.email
          }
        ]}
      />
    );
  }, [onClick, posX, posY, rowRecord]);

  ...

  <Table
    onRow={(record, _rowIndex) => {
      return {
        onContextMenu: (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          ...
          setRowRecord(record);
        },
        ...
      };
    }}
    ...
  />
```

Actually, the **rowRecord** state could be used inside our component immediately after we set the **record** value by using **setRowRecord** setter. But again, it depends on your own preference.

Comment: thank you! how do I get the row data (e.g. email address) into the <Menu>? For example if I right-click on "Foo" I want to have "baz@outlook.com" available in the <Menu> to call other functions.

Comment: you're welcome. I've just added an update to my post to answer your latest question.